# iOS UITableViewCell with scrollView with dynamic content

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a table view, in which the table view cells contain a scroll view. The scroll view can contain one or two pages of one image view each. Note that the scroll view will only scroll horizontally, so it will not interfere with the Table View's scroll view that will scroll vertically. Depending on the content, I want the scroll view to be updated with these image views, and set the scroll view content size according to responses I receive from a server, instructing the application what images to display.

In order to do that, I initially thought of creating a custom UITableViewCell subclass, and do  all my initialisation of the views inside that.

However, I am just thinking about performance and memory. I know that iOS automatically deallocates already seen views and cells, when it needs to, and that it reuses the old cells when it tries to display something new (by using a reuse identifier). However, each cell will contain a scroll view with content size and subviews that will change in each cell. I want to use a reuse identifier to ensure maximum performance.

Can anyone point me in a way in which I can set up the reuse of a cell like this, and change the contents of each scroll view successfully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make the reuseIdentifier dynamic
e.g. "cell_with_1","cell_with_2","cell_with_x" where x is the number of images

that way equal cells can be reused when sensible (e.g. when the number of images in the view is the same): 'worst case' is no reusing and a tad overhead for trying but in general I'd deem it beneficial :)

*the allocation deallocation and the basic adding of the subviews is expensive.. changing frames or images seems reasonable to me

Comment: Yes, but while resizing, I need to deallocate the extra image view in the second page, if it was created and the next cell only contains one image

Comment: ah :)... can you make the reuseIdentifier dynamic? e.g. "cell_with_1","cell_with_2","cell_with_x" where x is the number of pages

Comment: Hm... you definitely gave me an idea there. Won't that have impact in performance?

Comment: well it will allow reusing when sensible (e.g. when the number of images in the view is the same): 'worst case' is no reusing and a tad overhead for trying but in general I'd deem it beneficial

Comment: Thanks if you write the comment about the reuse identifier in a separate answer, I will mark it as the accepted one. I should note that I am now exploring putting a tableview inside a cell, so that I may achieve the same effect (see the application Pulse).